# CSS how to vertically center buttons in nav bar vertical align center not working

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to vertically center buttons in my navigation bar. Right now, they look like [this](https://gyazo.com/7c49ed7e292da3ae83da8c0e15614bc8) and I want them to be centered. Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Brian Eversole site">
    <title>Brian Eversole</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="indextest.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
/*CSS Reset*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;

}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 2em;
    border: black 1px solid;
    border-radius: .2em;
    padding: .01em;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: .5em;

}

nav ul {
     background-color: green;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: center;
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     height: 3em;

}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: grey;
    border: none;
}
```

Any help to center the buttons in the green bar would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove height from `nav ul`

```
nav ul {
 // height: 3em;
}
```

make `li` as `inline-block`

```
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top; //always use vertical align for inline-block element
}
```

make `a` block

```
nav a {
  display: block;
}
```

if you want custom height of nav, you can use flex

```
nav ul {
  height: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark your answer as right in a sec but first I have a few questions.

Comment: 1) What if I want to modify the size of the bar and keep it centered?

Comment: 2) Why would I do vertical-align: top instead of vertical-align: center? 3) Can you please explain what each of these do so that I understand why that works?

Comment: i have edited the answer. about `vertical-align`, you can use `top`, `middle`, `bottom` etc. google it to know all the values. but in this case i have used `vertical-align: top` just to reset extra value that `inline-block` gives.

Comment: Let me know if this helped you

Comment: I marked it as right, but I still don't funny understand. Why would you remove the height, make li inline-block, and make a block?

Comment: well, that's too much to explain. simply, with `inline-block` the `li` will arrange next to each other taking block property which is what `inline-block` is. it's hybrid of inline and block. since `li` is taking specific space with content, it's better to make `a` as block. even if you don't, it works fine. next about the height of nav, you don't need height in this case since you have already used equal top and bottom padding for `li` so it will be in the middle already if there is no height of parent.